# ACM's acmart clashes with libertine

Tags: libertine, acm, acmart

I'm preparing a document using the `acmart.cls` class file of ACM. When I compile, it keeps showing me this warning:

> Class acmart Warning: You do not have libertine package installed. Please upgrade your TeX on input line 611.

However, I can still compile, and get the pdf file. To get rid of this warning, I tried to install `libertine`. It then requires several other packages including `biolinum-type1`.

Now when I compile the file again, I got several errors, not warning.

```
! LaTeX Error: Unknown option `tt' for package `biolinum-type1'.
! LaTeX Error: Unknown option `type1' for package `biolinum-type1'.
! LaTeX Error: Unknown option `tt' for package `libertine-type1'.
! LaTeX Error: Unknown option `type1' for package `libertine-type1'.
```

I couldn't get the pdf file.

---

**Update**: I'm using Ubuntu 17, and my latex version is:

```
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/Debian)  
kpathsea version 6.2.2
```

---

**Update 2**: I accidentally figured out the problem. Actually I do not understand why there is the problem. But there is a package called `newtx`, and if I deleted it, the errors above disappeared, and I could compile a pdf file.

However, I installed `newtx` because `acmart` told me to do so. After I delete it, now I have the warning.

> You do not have `newtxmath` package installed.  Please upgrade your
>   TeX

Comment: I think you have to give more info like your Operating system and the versions+kind of latex+packages you are using (texlive and pdflatex etc)

Comment: @koleygr: I just added my set up.

Comment: This info will be needed to the next one who will find your question. I thought I could just download a cls file to test it  but it is more complicated. (your ubuntu is called 17.04 -year and month- but it is clear anyway)

Comment: Did you install libertine from https://ctan.org/tex-archive/install/fonts ? Note that https://ctan.org/pkg/biolinum-type1 says that this is obsolete so I imagine you shouldn't see this if you have a recent version of libertine.

Comment: @rocky Sorry, I couldn't remember where I got libertine from. It's definitely from ctan.org, which I found using Google.

Comment: On Ubuntu, if you’ve downloaded an old version of the packages and installed it manually, uninstall that. Then use `apt`to install either `texlive-full`, or at least `texlive-fonts-extra`, which contains the `libertine` and `newtxmath` packages, and `texlive-publishers`, which contains the `acmart`class and its prerequisites. See if you need any other TeX Live packages while you’re at it.

Comment: I would use the Ubuntu package manager to install the packages `texlive-fonts-extra` and `texlive-publishers`.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you installed an old version of `libertine`. Reinstall a new one from 
https://ctan.org/tex-archive/install/fonts

The CTAN information  on `biolinum-type1` says that is obsolete. From https://ctan.org/pkg/biolinum-type1 :

> The pack­age (and the com­pan­ion lib­er­tine-type1 pack­age of serif fonts) re­placed the lib­er­tine-legacy bun­dle. How­ever, the pack­ages do not pro­vide the range of font shapes avail­able with lib­er­tine-legacy.
>   The pack­age is now su­per­seded by the au­thor’s lib­er­tine font pack­age.

Also, I suspect you might also be able to ignore messages about a missing `libertine`. When I recently did using on a paper using `acmart` and option `acmtogs`, I got that message too and was able to ignore it.

However since you happen to be running this on Ubuntu, I'll add another tip. I needed to install install to `texlive-xetex` in addition to the other texlive debian packages.

One tool you might be able to use to help you track down problems is the system checker in [kile](http://kile.sourceforge.net/). So run

```
$ sudo apt install kile
$ kile
```

Then inside kile, in the very top toolbar (on my desktop it appears at the very upper left corner), select `Settings` → `System Check` and that will give you some idea if you've installed TeX and LaTeX properly.

Comment: I did all you said. The problem persists. Kile's system check stopped at 29% and never finished. I installed `texlive-xetex`, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Sounds to me like there are multiple things going wrong. And too few details you give or notice about what's up. (These things are perhaps related.)

Comment: the transitions from libertine to libertine-legacy to libertine-type1 back to libertine were a head-spinning period...

Comment: @jfbu Isn’t that always the flaw with the libertines? “For tomorrow we might die! (But, alas, we never do.)”

Answer (score 0):

If you installed TeX Live packages manually, I’d recommend uninstalling them and letting the Ubuntu package manager keep you up to date.  (Make sure Universe is in your list of repos.)  Alternatively, do a TeX Live install to `/usr/local`, make sure its `bin` directory appears before the system directories in your `PATH`, and run `tlmgr` regularly.  (If you do this, also put its documentation at the start of your `MANPATH`.)

By the way, you want to compile `acmart` documents with `xelatex` rather than `latex`.

If you don’t care about the disk space, just install `texlive-full`.

Since you’re using Ubuntu, a good technique is to search the package database for the package containing a given file.  If you want to install only packages you actually need, a search shows that `libertine.sty` and `newtxmath.sty` are in the package `texlive-fonts-extra` and `acmart.sty` (and its prerequisites) are in `texlive-publishers`.  You additionally will want to compile `acmart` documents in XeLaTeX, so make sure you have `texlive-xetex` installed.  You also probably want to make sure you have the packages in `texlive-plain-generic`, `texlive-latex-extra`, `texlive-fonts-extra-links`, `texlive-formats-extra`, `texlive-luatex`, `texlive-math-extra`, `texlive-pictures`, `texlive-lang-all` and `texlive-science`.  Also install their recommended packages.